# TTS doesn't initialize in Android 11

Tags: android, null, text-to-speech

I am working on Text-to-Speech.
The program I am trying to make, runs at API level 24, but it gives an error ("null") at level 30. The problem persists even though I added the following lines to the manifests file for Android 11.
Unfortunately, I could not find a source about this. I would be grateful if you could help me.

To Manifest

```
    ...

    <queries>
      <intent>
        <action
           android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
      </intent>
    </queries>

    ...
```

My Code:

```
    ...

      'tts = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {'

    ...
```